# Starting the Main activity from another activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to achieve following case on Android, but no success:
1) Launch Application (Launcher Activity which is a subclass of Base Activity). The Base Activity has code as follows:

```
///This is in BaseActivity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle instance)
{
    super.onCreate(instance);
    //Config.isLoggedIn() is a static function.
    if(! Config.isLoggedIn())
    {
        ////Config.startLoginActivity is a static function
        Config.startLoginActivity(this, getIntent());
        finish();
    }
}
```

The Config.startLoginActivity functions is defined as

```
public static void startLoginActivity(final Context ctx, final Intent finishIntent)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(ctx, ItemListActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra("FINISH_INTENT", finishIntent);
    ctx.startActivity(i);
}
```

Now, the ItemListActivity contains a list of Items as {Item1, Item2, Item3}. In ItemListActivity, I am saving the passed "finishIntent" as

```
///This is ItemListActivity onCreate Method
if(getIntent().hasExtra("FINISH_INTENT"))
        mFinishIntent = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("FINISH_INTENT");
```

and the onItemListSelected method is described as follows :

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(String id) {
Config.setLogInState(true);
    if(mFinishIntent != null)
    {

        Log.i("ITEMLISTACTIVITY", "Class Name = " + mFinishIntent.getClass().getName());
        Log.i("ITEMLISTACTIVITY", "Starting mFinishIntent Activity");
        startActivity(mFinishIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

But the issue is the Main Activity is not being launched again, Android takes me to the home screen instead. While looking for a solution, I saw that Google I/O app has the same implementation and that works flawlessly but in my case it is not. I am unable to figure it out. Please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Manifest File is as follows :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.app.myapplication.ItemListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

      <activity
        android:name="com.app.myapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: how about your Manifest - what activities have you declared there, which one is main? And by "Main activity is not being launched again" do you mean "BaseActivity" ?

Comment: I have added the manifest code. No, by Main Activity I mean "**com.app.myapplication.MainActivity**"

Comment: In onItemSelected, what's the output of `Log.i("ITEMLISTACTIVITY", "Class Name = "...` ? Also do you have a link to the original Google I/O sample?

Comment: [GoogleIO App](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/) 
output is Class Name = android.content.Intent

Answer (score 0):

Ok Here is a quick help which works for 100 percent which I'm using not mostly but EVERYTIME! you must past it through intent and in your case here it is how it must look like.

Intent intent = new intent(//name of your activity in which you are at the moment.this, //name of activity to which you want to go.class);
startActivity(intent);

Hope this will help